# Unable to install ROS Kinetic on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian-stretch

Im trying to install ROS Kinetic on my Raspberry Pi which is running Raspbian stretch.

When i enter

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

it returns

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I also tried to install ROS without apt-get but then i need to install all packages like rviz en rqt myself by cloning them from git, and i want to do that with apt-get

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the installation manual (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian). For me it looks like you either never updated your sources list or you did it but never updated your package index.

You have to:

1. Setup your sources.list (`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'`)
2. Set up your keys (`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654`)
3. Update your package index (`sudo apt-get update`)

before you can start installing the package.

**EDIT:** ROS Kinetic only supports jessie. You can try if `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'` works but there is absolutely no guarantee for it. You better should build ROS from source (http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source)

Comment: after i did this the error is still the same

Comment: I also installed dirmngr

Comment: After looking carefully at the installation page I saw the following: "ROS Kinetic ONLY supports Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages"

Answer (score 0):

For kinetic you should be working on Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages.

Install melodic if you are using updated one.